# Incompatibilidad y variaciones en las versiones de xampp

Tags: xampp

Por que xampp 7.4.29 tiene  php 7.4.29 y mariadb 10.4 y xampp 7.4.33 tiene php 7.4.33 y mariadb 5.4 o sea menor mariadb, quiero actualizar mi php pero me baja mi mariadb pq pasa esto o es que la versión 5.4 es mayor a la 10.4?

Comment: A menos que tengas un bug de PHP en tu aplicación que se corrija en la 7.4.33, no tiene mucho sentido actualizar desde la 7.4.29. Lo que si vale la pena es actualizar a la 8.2 ya que PHP 7.x (y 8.0) está obsoleto y [sin soporte](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php). Sin embargo si necesitas tener, si o si, la versión 7.4.33, lo que puedes hacer es tomar el directorio `php` del xampp 7.4.33 y reemplazarlo en el xampp más viejo.

Comment: 1.No has respondido mi pregunta, quiero saber pq en xampp 7.4.33 mariadb es de versión 5.4 y el xampp que tengo 7.4.29 tiene mariadb 10.4 pq una versión más moderna baja la versión de mariadb?2.por motivo ajenos a mi el servidor de php de producción es 7.4.X. el mariadb 10.4 mi php de desarrollo es 7.4.29 quiero actualizar al último 7.4 que es el 7.4.33 pero cuando instalo xampp 7.4.33 me da un mariadb 5.4 y no entiendo pq yo necesito actualizar mi php y al menos mantener mi mariadb no se pq xampp a mayor versión de php baja el mariadb tengo xampp 7.4.29 quiero subir sin bajar mariadb